# Unable to update Solr search results - error #500 cannot create the director

Tags: java, linux, apache, solr, lucene

I'm using Apache SOLR and attempting to update the xml file using the tutorial by Lucene: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_5_1/tutorial.html

Within the directory with the XML file, I should be able to input this command into the command line:

```
java -jar post.jar data.xml
```

And it updates the SOLR index results.

We are receiving the following error though: 
FATAL: Solr returned an error #500 Cannot create directory: /var/app/current/apache-solr-3.6.2/example/solr/./data/index java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /var/app/current/apache-solr-3.6.2/example/solr/./data/index

Comment: Have you started the Solr server with enough privileges to create the `data/index` directory?

Comment: I attempted to add permissions to directories, how do we set privileges for the data/index directory?

Comment: Investigate `chmod` and `chown`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not a basic permissions error, is something else trying to access the directory? A running instance of SOLR somewhere maybe?

Comment: This did it!  It was an instance we still had running that was blocking SOLR from running.  Good catch